# Python doctests and unicode

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, python-2.x, doctest

I have a code base that runs unchanged in Python 2.7 and 3.2+. But the doctests in the documentation rst files are giving me a headache. When I run them in Python2, I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb2' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)`. If I add

```
.. testsetup:: *

   from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

then I get a lot of errors like

```
Expected:
    'something'
Got:
    u'something'
```

Is there a way to have doctest containing unicode characters in the rst files that work unchanged in Python 2.7 and 3.2+?

Comment: Is it much work to actually specify the encoding to use when you run them?

Comment: @PauloBu: How you do this?

Comment: Well, I don't see code so it would be hard but, do you use the function `doctest.testfile` somewhere in your code? If so, please add to the question.

Comment: I don't. Doctests are called when I build the documentation using sphinx (`make doctest`). I get a similar error in the pypi registering. I was hoping to find a solution based on changing the rst file, not the call. In

Comment: Please add the code that gives you problems. And a traceback would be informative as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctest fails due to unicode leading u](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243623/doctest-fails-due-to-unicode-leading-u)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using Python 3.3. It added the explicit `u'unicode literals'` -- i.e. with `u` prefix again -- to ease the transition between Python 2 with unicode literals and Python 3. See http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-414-explicit-unicode-literals

Comment: For me, adding the `u'some string'` prefix makes the doctest fail even with Python 3.5

Comment: @matth The ignored `u` prefix for string literals is still valid for both for Python 3.5 and Python 3.6 (see https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringliteral). Can you create a minimalistic example that shows the problem?

Comment: I asked a new question here, it includes an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158733/unicode-literals-and-doctest-in-python-2-7-and-python-3-5

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473971/multi-version-support-for-python-doctests#comment18432670_13473971

Comment: As Martijn Pieters noted below the later question, there is no simple solution to bend the `doctest`. The reason is that the `u'string literal'` was reintroduced to Python 3.3 only to reuse the old sources easily. It is a compromise. The `u` prefix is simply ignored. This way, the string value will be the same if you use the prefix or not. On the other hand, the string representation will always be without the `u` prefix. The `doctest` is too simple to solve that compromise without any additional work. It is based on comparing of the string representations of the results.